# Has Apple already removed OpenGL support from OSX Monterrey?

Tags: macos, opengl, macos-monterey

My team develops an application that uses **OpenGL** (via OpenTK) and some users that have updated already to this version get a native crash when any of these functions are called:

```
GL.GetInteger(GetPName.FramebufferBinding, out var framebuffer);
GL.GetInteger(GetPName.StencilBits, out var stencil);
GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Samples, out var samples);
```

Comment: OpenGL has been deprecated in MacOS for years now. If this is its final removal, that should not come as a surprise.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with OpenTK, but the following issue describes that the problem is related to `NSLookupSymbolInImage` usage by OpenTK:
[OpenTK 3.x crashes MacOS Monterey Beta](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues/1308). Consider testing an updated OpenTK with a bugfix.

[image: NSLookupSymbolInImage deprecation]

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Non-programming based answer

As it's still in beta, it is hard to tell if OSX Monterrey is going to continue to support it. I believe the release of Monterrey is occurring in 2 hours, where we will learn about what is supported in it's first full release.

However, as OpenGL has been replaced by Vulkan, I don't know how likely the chances are. There is talk here that suggests OpenGL will require a 3rd-party patch to run GPU accelerated: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-12-monterey-on-unsupported-macs-thread.2299557/

Comment: As far as I understand, the given link tells about GPU-acceleration on obsolete GPUs not supporting Metal drivers, which are required by already released macOS versions (and OpenGL is implemented on top of Metal there). So I'm not sure that referred topic provides answer to OpenGL support on supported GPUs.